# Storing one-to-one Pointers on Both PFObjects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Classic pattern in Parse: one sets a pointer to a PFObject:

```
let fidoTheDog = PFObject(className: "Dog")
fidoTheDog["owner"] = PFUser.currentUser()
fidoTheDog.saveInBackground()
```

The pointer is stored on `fidoTheDog` but not on the other end:

I don't know who my dog is. I don't even know if I own a dog. I gotta go through the entire dog list to find which dog is mine.

So I add a pointer to `fidoTheDog` as my dog.

```
let fidoTheDog = PFObject(className: "Dog")
fidoTheDog["owner"] = PFUser.currentUser()
fidoTheDog.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { success, error in
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user["dog"] = fidoTheDog
    user.saveInBackground()
}
```

But now I have two requests, and it's ugly.

Is there a way to store pointers on both ends in one-go?

Comment: You don't really have to go through the entire list, you can do a query where key `owner` is equal to your user.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez you don't but the system will go thru the table to find a match, indexed or not. It is a lot less work on the part of system to get it directly from the owning object, as you know what you're looking for

Comment: It's more work, yes, but the server probably uses a binary search to find the owner, which is very fast (`O(log n)`, not as good as `O(1)`, but still very good). You also risk having inconsistent references, where `OwnerA`'s dog is `Dog1`, and `Dog1`'s owner is `OwnerB`. And even if you don't run into that, by only setting the owner of the dog, an owner can have multiple dogs. Both options have their pros and cons. If you want both references, you can use `saveAll`, as I mentioned in Alexander's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the dog PFObject and set it as the user's dog property and then save the user, Parse should recursively save any PFObjects that it points to.

```
    let fidoTheDog = PFObject(className: "Dog")
    fidoTheDog["owner"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    PFUser.currentUser()!["dog"] = fidoTheDog
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: that didn't work... `user.saveInBackground()` does not create the `Dog` object

Comment: @rayjohn in this case you can use `PFObject.saveAll([dog, user])` to save both objects. The `saveAll` call is a single request.

Comment: I edited it to not create a new user variable. I think using let to create the new user didn't let you edit the "dog" variable.

Comment: http://samwize.com/2015/06/24/pitfall-parse-circular-dependency-error-and-bidirectional-relationship/

Comment: Did you try the new edit? It works because the currentUser already has an objectId

Comment: Dunno whether to accept... this works for user only because the user by default has an objectId but wouldn't work for two objects that are being created simultaneously

Comment: It works if you have you're adding a child - parent relationship where any one already exists. If one does not already exist on Parse, it would be like trying to set the property of an object to an object that doesn't exist yet. In which case, you would have to create each one sequentially like you did. However, any object already created must have an objectId